# how to make SQLAlchemy to_json function that doesnt add column type to ouput?

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an association object that accesses two fields in its to_json function. One is a string and one is a decimal number

here is the object:

```
class DrinkIngredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'drink_ingredient'
    drink_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("drink.id"), primary_key=True)
    ingredient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("ingredient.id"), primary_key=True)
    units = db.Column(db.Numeric(4, 2)) # Total of 4 digits, 2 after decimal: 00.00

    ingredient = db.relationship("Ingredient")

    def __init__(self, ingredient=None, units=None):
        self.ingredient = ingredient
        self.units = units

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<DrinkIngredient %g units of %r>' % (self.units, self.ingredient)

    def to_json(self):
        json_drinkIngredient = {
            "ingredient": self.ingredient.name,
            "amount": self.units
        }
        return json_drinkIngredient
```

Ingredient.name is a string in another table called `Ingredient`.

When i call this function I get an output like this
`{'amount': Decimal('0.20'), 'ingredient': u'grenadine'}`

why is the `Decimal('...')` and `u'...'` being included and how do i correctly make these json objects without the type listed.

Also this isn't a huge concern but i'd rather them be in the reverse order as that is the order i defined them in and I'm not sure why they aren't in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the json module to output proper json.

```
from simplejson import dumps

def to_json(self):
    json_drinkIngredient = dumps({
        "ingredient": self.ingredient.name,
        "amount": self.units
    })
    return json_drinkIngredient
```

About your second question, the reason is that python dictionaries are unordered. If it's important to maintain the order with which you declared the keys use an `OrderedDict` and pass that object to `json.dumps`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d=OrderedDict()
d['ingredient']=self.ingredient.name
d['amount']=self.units
```

Comment: i wasnt aware there existed this json module. Is it a part of pythons base?

Comment: yep, standard python, batteries included!

Comment: i am getting ` Decimal('1.00') is not JSON serializable` error when i use json.dumps()

Comment: right, forgot about this encoder issue of json. use `simplejson` instead, install using `pip install simplejson`, as that one supports decimal encoding. it has the same functions. answer updated.

Comment: gotcha thanks so much, is simplejson a standard or something?

Comment: no, but is available in pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson and source code in github: https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson